# Apache Does Not Start from Desired Location via the XAMPP Control Panel

Tags: wordpress, apache, xampp

I would like to install WordPress on an external USB drive connected to my local Windows 11 workstation so I can design and try out new websites without immediately posting to an online and public hosting service.

To that end, I installed XAMPP on the above-mentioned hard drive and need to be able to use Apache through the XAMPP control panel. However, Apache will not start. Every time I try to start Apache the log in the bottom portion of the XAMPP control panel has a line that states "Attempting to start Apache service..." and nothing more. And I can't connect to my localhost using any of my browsers.

Also, I noticed that, when I open the XAMPP Control Panel (always in Administrator Mode), the log section in the control panel window includes, in red,...

> 8:29:34 PM  [Apache]  Apache Service detected with wrong path
> 8:29:34 PM  [Apache]  Change XAMPP Apache and Control Panel settings or
> 8:29:34 PM  [Apache]  Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
> 8:29:34 PM  [Apache]  Found Path: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Promise\Pegasus Utility\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice
> 8:29:34 PM  [Apache]  Expected Path: "i:\xampp\apache\bin\httpd.exe" -k runservice

I've attached an image of the XAMPP Control Panel with the error message.

I did try to connect to `http://localhost` with my web browser and it did not work.

[XAMPP Control Panel with error messages.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tv3Sl.png)

I tried to change, via the Config button, the port associated with Apache but that didn't work.

So, to judge from the log in the control panel, Apache was already installed earlier on the startup (C:) drive of my computer. But, I'm trying to have Apache, MySQL and the rest of the XAMPP apps reside on my separate (I:) drive, because I want to use that I: drive to build my new websites offline with WordPress.

I suppose I could uninstall/remove the copy of Apache that's on the C: drive. However, given its location in the Promise and Promise Utility folders, I think my Promise Pegasus RAID drive relies on it. I need my RAID to be available at all times. Therefore, I don't really want to tamper with any files related to it, including the copy of Apache on that C: drive.

Given all this, could you please provide suggestions on how can I have a copy of Apache work via the XAMPP Control Panel on my external drive?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1**

I changed the ports for Apache in httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.conf (at least I think those were the two files I was supposed to change). But then, when I tried to remove Apache as a service by unchecking the box next to it, XAMPP could not uninstall it.

XAMPP gives me a similar error message about Apache already existing in a different location than where I would like it to be.

Here's what my Control Panel looks like now:
[XAMPP Control Panel after Apache was not uninstalled.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iXV0U.png)

What should I try next?

I feel as if this is so close to being resolved, as if there are just one or two more steps...But what are they?

**EDIT 2: Sn 3/3/24**

I restarted the XAMPP Control Panel with the boxes under Service left unchecked for both Apache and MySQL. MySQL has started successfully.

I'm still having issues starting Apache, but now the error is different. It reads...

> 6:09:53 PM  [Apache]  Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
> 6:09:53 PM  [Apache]  This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
> 6:09:53 PM  [Apache]  improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
> 6:09:53 PM  [Apache]  Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
> 6:09:53 PM  [Apache]  the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
> 6:09:53 PM  [Apache]  If you need more help, copy and post this  
> 6:09:53 PM  [Apache]  entire log window on the forums

I thought I changed the port already. So, I guess something else is causing Apache to crash. But, what, exactly? I'm not really sure which log to check.

Help, please.

Comment: *"how can I have a copy of Apache work via the XAMPP Control Panel on my external drive?"* - configure the xampp's apache to use port other than `80` and `443`, don't forget to configure it on `httpd.conf` and one another file which i forgot the name of. oh also, configure the xampp control panel to look for your configured ports. remember to never enable apache as a service (that green checklist beside apache) in xampp **if you want it to be portable**. at this point i suspect your xampp control panel already nuked your Pegasus Utility apache service.

Comment: Thanks, @BagusTesa. I followed your advise, but now Apache is crashing and XAMPP displays a different error log. See the details above under my Edit 2 section.

Comment: does pressing start not working?

Comment: have you take a look at *"the **Windows Event Viewer** for more clues"*, perhaps that pegasus used the same port? also, **always** run the xampp control panel as admin. i genuinely never used that pegasus thing so i can't tell what port it used, i keep track what port my machine uses so i won't have headache later.. i learned the hard way back then.

Comment: Hi, @BagusTesa. No clicking Start does not work. Apache, apparently, begins to start then shuts down unexpectedly and XAMPP displays an error accordingly. In Event Viewer, what clues would I look for exactly? (I'm not someone who's proficient with servers or web admin, so, right now, I'm feeling rather lost.)

Comment: There had been a different issue (extremely slow internet browsing speeds) that forced me to ultimately reinstall Windows 11 and all my apps from scratch. Afterward, MySQL started crashing. I tried to change the MySQL port. Now it works, though, oddly, it appears to still be using the same port as it was originally (3306). Apache is also using its original ports (80 and 443). Don't know if the clean install helped. Regardless, Apache, MySQL and the rest of XAMPP are finally working correctly and so is WordPress. I can finally start to design my site. Thanks very much for your help, @BagusTesa.

Comment: *"oddly, it appears to still be using the same port as it was originally"* - errr, did you configure the one in xampp control panel or the `httpd.conf` and `httpd-ssl.conf` for apache, `my.ini` for mysql? the xampp control panel one is for "ports to check" while those config are the one that  used by each application. but hey, glad you worked out. tbh, I confused with the happenings on your machine too.